# IndentationError: Indentation error while running code

Tags: python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python     
def printMatrix(matrix,rows,columns,row):
print matrix[row-1][columns-1]
if __name__=='__main__':
     matrix=[]
with open('matrix1.txt','r') as f:
for l in f:
 t=l.split(',')
  matrix.append(t)
printMatrix(matrix, 3, 3, 1)
```

I am using the above code, and am getting an error print matrix[row-1][columns-1]
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block.

Any leads please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python expects an indented line after the def statement. (Indentation in Python is syntactically important, since it doesn't use braces or parentheses for everything in the way that some other languages do.)

e.g.

```
def square(n):
    return n * n
```

Also indent after fors and ifs. I'm not able to test your code, but my best guess is it should be formatted something like this:

```
def printMatrix(matrix,rows,columns,row):
    print matrix[row-1][columns-1]
    if __name__=='__main__':
        matrix=[]
    with open('matrix1.txt','r') as f:
        for l in f:
            t=l.split(',')
            matrix.append(t)
printMatrix(matrix, 3, 3, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your indentation worked. I defined my matrix however, when i run the code it says  printMatrix(matrix, 3, 3, 1)
NameError: name 'matrix' is not defined

Comment: You need to define the variable "matrix" earlier in your code. Try adding the line: matrix = [] before the def line.